# Could someone explain what I am doing wrong with this 2d array game

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I have spent 4 days with this one issue and have search countless of possible solutions and now I am pulling out my hair. I am trying to get a minesweeper 2d character array game to first count the mines surrounding(basically the 8 blocks surrounding the mine) a mine then convert the characters surrounding the mines to integers. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could help. This is homework that is due tomorrow. I feel like such a dummy, but I have literally spent sleepless nights working on this one issue. :'( Someone please help
example  m is mine 
here is part of a void method that is suppose to check the areas around a mine and convert them to numbers calling the  adjacentMines method

```
    for(this.rows = 0; rows < board.length; rows++) {
           for(this.cols = 0; cols < board[rows].length; cols++) {  

            for(int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
                        for(int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
                            if(i == 0 && j == 0) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            else 
                                if(inBounds(rows + i, cols + j))
                                board[i][j]=(char)(48+adjacentMines(i,j));

                            }
                        }

            }
    }      
    }
```

When I want something like this
I want it to look like this when I select a cordinate, where x is the selected coordinate and not a mine, so I want to the output like this. The array above is just the current state, I want numbers to replace the e in the output
        | 0 | 1 | 0 | 
        | 0 | x | 1 |
        | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Hi John, so what happens when you run the code? Does it error out or produce unexpected output?

If you could, maybe show what you expect and what the program returns currently

Comment: @ire_and_curses, why did you tag this as [tag:c]?

Comment: @Alexander - Because I thought it was (maybe C++)? Or is this Java? Please feel free to retag. I wanted to get a (valid) language tag on here since that will add many more eyes.

Comment: The language is not clear anyways

Comment: So sorry, when I run it I get this array ceeeeemeee
eeeeee0eee
meeemmeeem
0eee80eem0
eeee0eee0e
eeeeeeeeee
eeeeeeeeee
eeeeeemeee
eemeee8eee
ee0eee0eee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an empty statement:

```
if(inBounds(row + i, col + j)&&mineBoard[row][col]==true);
```

Notice the semi-colon at the end.

Also, in the latter snippet of code, the loops for `i` and `j` are redundant. You should get rid of them, and you shouldn't be counting mines for occupied cells.

Comment: Thank you, I think I just did that by accident, I have tried everything I have been rewriting code for days and no sleep. It is still not working

Comment: thanks, I edited the mineBoard and it is closer to what I wanted

Comment: @john, sorry for not being of much help but the information that you provide is insufficient to give you more hints. For example, I can see the relevance between your snippet and the table at the end of your question, those two seems to be unrelated